# Prove: If $\alpha=((n+ \sqrt{n^2-4})/2)^m$ when $n\geqslant2$ and $m$ are natural numbers, prove that $\alpha=(k+\sqrt{k^2-4})/2$, $k\in\Bbb N$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, contest-math, quadratics

Consider the number
$$
    \alpha=\left(\frac{n+ \sqrt{n^2-4}}2\right)^m
$$
where $n\geqslant2$ and $m$ are natural numbers.
Prove that
$$
    \alpha=\frac{k+\sqrt{k^2-4}}2
$$
for some $k\in\Bbb N$.

What I've tried:

I noticed that $\alpha$ can be seen as a root raised to the $m$-th power, for a quadratic expression $x^2 -nx +1$.  However, I am not sure how to leverage this to get to the required answer.

Comment: [Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34121/42969). Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. – For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Hint: define $\beta_\pm:=(n\pm\sqrt{n^2-4})/2$, then check $\beta_+\beta_-=1$.

Comment: Can you add some more context here @J.G. Not getting it....

Comment: @mk8 , Assume $\displaystyle \beta_{\pm} $ to be the roots of $\displaystyle x^2 -nx +1 .$ Then find an equation whose root are $\displaystyle \beta_{\pm}^m ,$ this equation will come out to be quadratic of form $\displaystyle x^2 -kx +1.$  Now, $\displaystyle \beta_{\pm}^m \equiv \alpha_{\pm} .$ Thus $\displaystyle \alpha_+  = \frac{k + \sqrt{k^2-4}}{2}.$

Answer (score 1):

For $n=2$ is obvious. Let $n>2$ integer. Then the equation
$$
x^2-nx+1=0
$$
has two roots $r,s$, both real, satisfying
$$
0<r=\frac{n-\sqrt{n^2-4}}{2}<1<s=\frac{n+\sqrt{n^2-4}}{2}
$$
We shall show inductively, in $k$, that $r^k,s^k$ are the roots of $x^2-n_kx+1=$, for a suitable $n_k>2$ positive integer.

For $k=1$ is already known. Also, $r^ks^k=1$ for all $k\in\mathbb N$.

Assume that for some $k$, we have $r^j+s^j=n_j\in\mathbb N$, for all $j=1,\ldots,k$.  Then

$$
n\cdot n_k=(r+s)(r^k+s^k)=r^{k+1}+s^{k+1}+rs(r^{k-1}+s^{k-1})
=(r+s)(r^k+s^k)=r^{k+1}+s^{k+1}+(r^{k-1}+s^{k-1})
$$
and hence
$$
r^{k+1}+s^{k+1}=n\cdot n_k-(r^{k-1}+s^{k-1})=n\cdot n_k-n_{k-1}.
$$
Clearly $n_{k+1}=r^{k+1}+s^{k+1}$ is an integer, and it is positive since $r,s>0$. Also, $r^{k+1},s^{k+1}$ are clearly the roots of $x^2-n_{k+1}x+1$, because their product is 1 and their sum is $n_{k+1}$.

Answer (score 0):

$n=2$ is trivial.  For any integer $n>2$, let $\alpha_m = \displaystyle \left(\frac{n+\sqrt{n^2-4}}2\right)^m = \alpha_1^m$.

As $\alpha_1$ is a root of the quadratic $x^2-nx+1$, we can substitute $\alpha_1$ and multiply throughout by $\alpha_1^m$ to get that $\alpha_i$ satisfies the recursion $\alpha_{m+2}-n\,\alpha_{m+1}+\alpha_m=0$ or $2\alpha_{m+2}=2n\,\alpha_{m+1}-2\alpha_m$.  It can be checked easily that $2\alpha_1, 2\alpha_2$ are of the form $a+b\sqrt{n^2-4}$ for integers $a, b$, hence the recursion guarantees $\alpha_m$ is also of desired form.

Comment: Should it not be  (n+ Sqareroot(n^2-4) ), and not (n - Sqareroot(n^2-4) )?

Comment: @mk8 Thanks - the sign of that term has been corrected, hopefully shouldn't affect anything else.